# Bootstrap v5.0 - problem with swapping columns

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

Please help! I am new to bootstrap and can't get my head around an issue I am having. Basically in the image(s) attached, I want the coin image to be above its respective text on the left when it reduces to a smaller screen. At present when I move to a smaller screen the image will always show underneath the text. I've tried push/pull, nothing happens. I've tried using ['order'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kb3K8.png), as seen in highlighted code. But this only swaps them over when in a large screen, when I reduce to a smaller screen the image always stays below. And I've tried [offset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaoGp.png), which works, however, the text doesn't stay inline with the image. I understand from what I've read that push/pull is not used in v5.0 but I cannot find what I am doing wrong.
Any advice/guidance would be most appreciated. TYI

Comment: Have you tried including breakpoints when using `order`? Eg `order-sm-1 order-md-2`. I would hope this makes the coin Div appear first on small screens but second on medium screens and above (as in your example).

Comment: please post question with your try codeded.

Comment: I've tried doing order-sm-1 and order-md-2 but that didn't work.  Swaps them over on a medium screen size but image is still beneath text when its small screen size.

Comment: @HDP the code I have used is in my images which are included in my post, click on either 'orders' or 'offset' to see my images. the CSS side I have is: .midsect{
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    
}

Comment: @Senna please see other question for how to should add proper question in stack overflow.

Comment: Please take a [tour] and  read [ask], or even [answer]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out after having a break and more reading on the web. For my coin image I had to enter 'order-md-last order-first' within my class for that column, which translates as 'order last on medium and wider' and 'order first on small'.